# What does the following C++ line of code mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, struct

The following block of code is taken from a C++ program which implements a queue. I know struct, classes and pointer etc. but I dont use struct a lot so it is giving me a hard time understanding what `*front = NULL,*rear = NULL,*p = NULL,*np = NULL;` means. Are these node type pointers being declared and are being set to a default value of NULL? Please correct me if I'm wrong and kindly explain.

```js
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
}*front = NULL,*rear = NULL,*p = NULL,*np = NULL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
node *front = NULL, *rear = NULL, *p = NULL, *np = NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

It means the same as this:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

node *front = NULL;
node *rear = NULL;
node *p = NULL;
node *np = NULL;
```

And it is definitely no good style.

By the way, this would also work if `node` was a class. A struct is basically a class with all elements being public by default.

Another recommendation: C++11 has a specific keyword `nullptr` for initializing pointers. This expresses more clearly what is happening. `NULL` is just a preprocessor macro that expands to 0.